# Import Bean Shell into Java Class

Tags: java, import, beanshell

My file structure:

```
workspace
--packageA
----classA
----classB
--beanshellClass1
--beanshellClass2
```

I want to import beanshellClass2 in my classA, I attempted to use

```
import beanshellClass2;
```

I got error:

```
The import beanshellClass2 cannot be resolved
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

the beanshell classes must also be in packages, otherwise you cannot import them